# How do i increase my jquery slice by 5 on click?

Tags: jquery, slice

I need jquery slice to show the next 5 divs of a list of divs on click how do i go about increasing the length of my slice variables on click?

```
var $p1 = 0;
var $p2 = 5;
var $increaseslice = (function () {
    $p1 + 5;
    $p2 + 5;
});
var $divselector = $('.date-sheet > .date-sheet-row');

console.log($p1 + $p2);
// Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
$($divselector).slice($p1, $p2).css('display', 'block');
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    console.log();
    $($divselector).slice($p1, $p2).hide('slow');
    $increaseslice();
    console.log($p1 + $p2);
    $($divselector).slice($p1, $p2).show('slow');
});
```

This is what i currently have but it just loops through the same 5 divs everytime...
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLxTB/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use += to add 5 to it

```
$p1 += 5; // same as $p1 = $p1 + 5
$p2 += 5; // same as $p2 = $p2 + 5
```